# how to find the first consonant sql in varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table Person{name, surname, location} and i want to select those surname that their first consonant is the same. For example: "Adams" and "Eodens" their first consonant is "d"

Comment: Do you want Lisa, Alfred and Alberta too? They share the same first consonant L.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the first consonant using a regular expression, e.g.:

```
substring(surname from '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]')
```

This can be used with an EXISTS condition to find all rows that have the same value for that expression:

```
select p1.*, substring(p1.surname from '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]') as first_consonant
from person p1
where exists (select *
              from person p2
              where substring(p1.surname from '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]') = substring(p2.surname from '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]')
                and p1.id <> p2.id)
order by first_consonant
```

The `id` column is assumed to be a primary (or unique) key in order to distinguish the rows.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f28240fab246fa897125bbb725503f71)

Answer (score 1):

You should write a function([see tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-function/)) that returns the first consonant of a given string argument. Ensure to mark it as `IMMUTABLE` function when you create it. Then you could create a `computed` aka generated [column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html) based on that `surname` column, then you should do a `self join` on that table to select those records that have the same `value` for that computed column.

Comment: using `substring(surname from '[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]')` will work too as in other answer, but note the multiple times execution of the `substring` function, it is overhead. In my answer, the first consonant is obtained _once_ when the record initially gets inserted/updated, at other retrieval times it is not executed, so it is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a (case insensitive) regular expression match operation.

```
SELECT *
       FROM person
       WHERE surname ~* '^[^bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*d';
```

The `^` at the beginning of the pattern matches the beginning of the string. `[^bcd...]` is a negated (because of the `^`) class to match all characters that aren't consonants -- because of the negation it lists all consonants -- (that way not only vowel letters match but other characters like interpunctation too). `*` quantifies these characters to an arbitrary count. Finally `d` is the character you search for. So from the beginning of the string there can be an arbitrary number of non consonants followed by `d`.